# How to write a handy MVVM-Keylistener

Tags: wpf, mvvm, keylistener

I need to write a keylistener in a WPF-application. I want to be able to process any key. The application complies the MVVM-pattern.

I am aware of the pure XAML-Solution, but it's not universal for every key:

```
<KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" CommandParameter="EnterPressed" />
```

I don't want to write this for every possible Key. Is there any way to implement a handy KeyListener that does not break MVVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an easy way to bind the pressed key to a variable in the ViewModel without breaking the MVVM pattern. It uses a Binding that is created and filled in code-behind:

1. Create a DependencyProperty and a Binding in the constructor of the window:

   ```
   Binding binding = new Binding();
   binding.Path = new PropertyPath("pressedKey");
   binding.Source = DataContext;
   binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;
   dp = DependencyProperty.Register("pressedKey", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));
   BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, dp, binding);
   ```
2. Set an Eventhandler in XAML:

   ```
   KeyDown="KeyDown_Handler"
   ```
3. Assign the value of the pressed key to the DependencyProperty:

   ```
   private void KeyDown_Handler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       SetValue(dp, e.Key.ToString());
   }
   ```

If the public `pressedKey`-Variable exists in ViewModel, it will contain the pressed key. In the set-block or by calling the ViewModel to execute a Command (`((ICommand)DataContext).Execute(...)`) you can process the pressedKey immediately